# Xamarin.Forms image with minus margin inside frame not overlapping in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

the image inside Frame with minus margin on top for overlapping but as you see its cutting on edges of the frame

**Update Question Add full-page code** I remove bottom part

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:AgentWay.Helpers;assembly=AgentWay"
             xmlns:layouts="clr-namespace:AgentWay.Layouts;assembly=AgentWay"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CustomControls.Controls;assembly=CustomControls"
             xmlns:base="clr-namespace:AgentWay.Pages;assembly=AgentWay"
             NavigationPage.TitleView="{Binding TitleView}"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="{Binding HasNavFlag}"
             x:Class="AgentWay.Pages.WelcomePage">

    <Grid x:Name="WelcomeScrole" VerticalOptions="Center"   >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame Grid.Row="1"  >
          <ContentView Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,-80,0,0" >
            <Image HeightRequest="150"  Source="WelcomeLogo"   />
        </ContentView>
        </Frame>


    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

updated image with frame + image only 
[image]

Comment: I don't think Frame works that way. It could help to show us an example of what you're trying to attempt so we can possibly give better suggestions

Answer (score 1):

when we use Grid layout, screen divided into rows and columns which depends on columns and rows definition .

Height always depends on numbers of rows.

Width also depends on columns.

Here, in your code you set Grid.Row=0 to frame.It only contains that fixed height which you define to Row definition .

suppose you're using **4 rows then single row occupies 25% of screen height**.
Also same for columns.

In your code you set minus margin to image view , which always remains in row not outside of frame.

```
<Frame Grid.Row="0"  >     
     <Image Aspect="AspectFit"  Source="WelcomeLogo" VerticalOption="Center" HorizontalOption="Center"  />    
</Frame>
```

Comment: yea makes sense but this could be fixed with minus padding only

Comment: @MinaFawzy just use Grid.RowSpan and adjust your image view with any height with AspectFit.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you then upvote answer and happy coding:).